# set srid in hibernate annotation

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

i work on gis project with spring boot 2.1 and hibernate and mysql 8.

i have a table with this detail

```
@Data
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Place {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long Id;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "point")
    Point point;

    String tittle;
    String text;

    @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    @JsonIgnore
    private long createdDate;

    @Column(name = "modified_date")
    @LastModifiedDate
    @JsonIgnore
    private long modifiedDate;

    @org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedBy
    @JsonIgnore
    Long CreatedBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @JsonIgnore
    Long ModifiedBy;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="city_id",nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private City city;
}
```

i want add index for point but mysql get me warning that :

The spatial index on column 'point' will not be used by the query optimizer since the column does not have an SRID attribute. Consider adding an SRID attribute to the column.

how i add srid attribute to the point with annotation and how add spatial index to point with annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with *column definition*. Tested with Hibernate 5.4.2 and MySQL 8.0.

```
@Entity
public class GeometryEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  // only allow geometries with SRID 4326 and not null (be able to create spatial indexes)
  @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "GEOMETRY SRID 4326")
  private Geometry geometry;

  private void setId(final Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setGeometry(final Geometry geometry) {
    this.geometry = geometry;
  }

  public Geometry getGeometry() {
    return geometry;
  }

}
```

See also:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-type-overview.html

Comment: What SRID value should be used for the Geo Coordinates value?